# How to restore the oldest version of multiple specific files from backup (Windows7) automatically

Tags: windows, backup

Some unknown time ago, I seem to have overwritten my JPEG files with the corrupt version from memory cards or something. Fortunately I have backup of these files created with Backup and Restore (Windows7) tool.

The problem is that, since there seem to be so many corrupt files across multiple folders, some sharing same file name, it is cumbersome to find the target file with GUI of Backup and Restore tool. Hence I am looking for *a way to extract the oldest version of a specific file from the backup automatically*.

Given a full file path of target files (e.g. `C:\foo\bar\baz.jpg`) and a location of Windows7 backup (e.g. `Z:\PCNAME\MediaID.bin`), is there a command or something to extract the oldest version of each target files? I can handle some programming (Windows batch, Powershell script, C#, Python) if needed.